# Python type hinting to return class in function

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function similar to below. I want the type hinting to return Bar but this seems to be invalid. Is there a way to do this or do i have to move the class outside the function to reference it as a return type?

```
def foo(i: int) -> Bar:
    class Bar:
        def __init__(i: int):
            self.i = i
    return Bar(i)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annotation is meaningless, because your function returns instances of a *new, distinct `Bar` class* each time it is called.

In other words, there is no *one* `Bar` class against which you can check the type. The result of `type(foo(1)) is type(foo(2))` is *always going to be false*, so a type check against `type(foo(1))` is always going to fail when you pass in `foo(2)` too.

If you want type checking to apply here, you'll need to declare a base class:

```
class BaseBar: pass

def foo(i: int) -> BaseBar:
    class Bar(BaseBar):
        def __init__(i: int):
            self.i = i
    return Bar(i)
```

To make this a bit more readable, the base class could just be named `Bar` and the function could produce a `BarImpl` or `ConcreteBar` or similar. That way you can keep using `Bar` in type annotations everywhere to reduce confusion.

You don't actually seem to *need* to create a new class each time; nothing in the class is parameterised or uses closures; if this is true for your actual code, then you could just define it *outside* the function:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(i: int):
        self.i = i

def foo(i: int) -> Bar:
    return Bar(i)
```

Comment: It hadn't even occurred to me that i was creating a new class every time. I was just trying to keep the namespace from being cluttered but if this is correct i'll get better performance from moving the class elsewhere and calling it from there.

Comment: @Ajurna: absolutely. A `class ...:` statement is an *executable statement*. It is executed as soon as Python comes across it. Modules are executed when first imported, and the class object that results is then stored at the global level. Here you create it as a local variable in a function, and it is executed each time the function is called.